# How can LinkedIn know about my Yahoo contacts?

Tags: privacy, linkedin

I signed up to LinkedIn using a Yahoo account. I confirmed the address from their email message, but I refused to allow them to access my address book. So the site showed:

> Confirm your Yahoo! account.
>   Click below to sign in with Yahoo! and verify your email address.
>   We'll let you know if your Yahoo! contacts are on LinkedIn even if you don't add your address book.

How can they do that even if I refuse address book access?

Answer (score 3):

They might checked your e-mail address in other users address book (people who did agree giving their addressbook).